# Analysis of complex sample

Tags: chi-squared-test, survey, sample, stratification

The company where I work did a survey with a complex sample. Originally, the sample was a 2-step stratified, but due to some problems, we lost one of them (so, let's consider that the sample is stratified only on 1 variable).

The biggest part of the questions is like "What you think the company can do in respect of X?" and then there is a list of options (some questions allow only 1 answer, some more than 1, others are Likert-type response options).

My question is: Wow can I analyze this data? It would be nice if there were a test like Chi-square for complex sample (probably there exists one, but I don't know)

Any software is welcome, but I prefer R and SPSS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are lots of methods for dealing with complex survey data. Almost all of them require you to be able to specify the complex structure of the sampling framework.

In R there is the `survey` package (see [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survey/index.html) repository for help files) by Thomas Lumley, who has also written a [book](http://books.google.co.nz/books/about/Complex_Surveys.html?id=9wN0HbBEmb0C) on the topic "Complex surveys: A guide to data analysis in R", which is quite readable from a theoretical perspective and very useful from the applied perspective (so useful that my copy is currently sitting in a colleagues office.)

I haven't tried complex survey analysis in SPSS: you need an [add-on](http://www-142.ibm.com/software/products/us/en/spss-complex-samples/) to do anything that takes proper account of survey design (which will cost you money.)

But the R package should do everything you want it to do, for free, and with the greater flexibility that comes with R.

Comment: agree with @James ..also check out [the main website](http://faculty.washington.edu/tlumley/survey/) and [click here](http://faculty.washington.edu/tlumley/survey/example-chisq.html) for example code on chi-squared tests with survey data  :)

Comment: @AnthonyDamico The second link doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @StudentT https://web.archive.org/web/20121020040904/http://faculty.washington.edu/tlumley/survey/example-chisq.html