# Alternatives to svychisq() in survey

Tags: r, survey, sample

A time ago I posted [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51861/analysis-of-complex-sample) question. Now I have a 'little' continuation: I'm having some difficult with a few questions, getting this error message:

```
> svychisq(~ p13 + p14, amostra)
Error in solve.default(denom, numr) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 4.64501e-18
```

There is any alternative package/analisys? Or, at least, an explanation to my boss of why I can't analyse this data :P

EDIT 2:

Data and commands (sorry for the long `dput()`). p11 is the stratum, poulacao is the stratum population size, p13 and p14 are two questions.

```
require(survey)
dados_censo <- structure(list(p11 = c(16L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 11L, 12L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 16L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 17L, 18L, 17L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 
18L, 18L, 11L, 2L, 2L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 22L, 22L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 18L, 18L, 10L, 
16L, 16L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 16L, 26L, 20L, 26L, 9L, 1L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 13L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 18L, 
13L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 13L, 13L, 6L, 6L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 
9L, 10L, 6L, 6L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 18L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 17L, 17L, 21L, 10L, 10L, 
14L, 6L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 13L, 13L, 3L, 24L, 9L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 9L, 9L, 13L, 13L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 8L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 9L, 13L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
19L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 19L, 19L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
14L, 14L, 13L, 13L, 9L, 8L, 27L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 24L, 
16L, 16L, 6L, 6L, 11L, 13L, 11L, 26L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 14L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 14L, 3L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 27L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 4L, 19L, 19L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 26L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 6L, 26L, 
26L, 27L, 7L, 7L, 19L, 27L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 26L, 26L, 
20L, 26L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 25L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 25L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 18L, 18L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 18L, 24L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 14L, 2L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 13L, 13L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 26L, 24L, 8L, 8L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 24L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 24L, 18L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 26L, 24L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 
26L, 16L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 10L, 
19L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 26L, 26L, 24L, 20L, 
27L, 27L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
13L, 11L, 11L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 16L, 16L, 27L, 19L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 11L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
19L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 19L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 13L, 13L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 26L, 26L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 13L, 26L, 11L, 13L, 23L, 23L, 15L, 23L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 11L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 11L, 9L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 10L, 19L, 13L, 13L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 3L, 19L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 21L, 21L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 21L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 11L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 
13L, 13L, 21L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 27L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 24L, 24L, 
11L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 19L, 19L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 19L, 19L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 13L, 13L, 19L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 19L, 19L, 24L, 24L, 13L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 25L, 19L, 19L, 11L, 19L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 19L, 11L, 13L, 13L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 6L, 6L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 19L, 
13L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 13L, 19L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 13L, 19L, 19L, 14L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
11L, 19L, 19L, 13L, 11L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 19L, 19L, 13L, 13L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 19L, 13L, 13L, 19L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 21L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 13L, 
11L, 24L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 13L, 13L, 15L, 14L, 2L, 25L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 23L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 19L, 13L, 19L, 19L, 13L, 
13L, 24L, 24L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 26L, 26L, 24L, 19L, 11L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 24L, 13L, 24L, 24L, 19L, 13L, 
11L, 11L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 13L, 19L, 19L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 9L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 19L, 19L, 13L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 2L, 13L, 11L, 19L, 18L, 19L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 19L, 19L, 18L, 25L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 19L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 11L, 19L, 11L, 11L, 18L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 11L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 18L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 25L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 13L, 13L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 13L, 25L, 19L, 19L, 13L, 13L, 25L, 
13L, 25L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 13L, 13L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L), p13 = c(4L, 
4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
5L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 
7L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 
8L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 
7L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 
7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 
7L, 8L, 4L, 3L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 
7L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 
6L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 
1L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 
5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 5L, 
7L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 
7L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 6L, 
5L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 3L, 
6L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
8L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 
6L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 
6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 
6L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 
5L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 8L, 
7L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 
5L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 
5L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 
8L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 
8L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 
5L, 8L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 
2L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 
7L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 
6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
5L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 6L, 2L, 
7L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
6L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 
5L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 
8L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
4L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 8L, 
6L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 
6L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 
8L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
1L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 
4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 
8L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 
1L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 
2L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 
7L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
8L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 
4L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 
6L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 
3L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 
6L, 8L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 
1L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 
2L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 
2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 
8L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
6L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 1L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 
5L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 
4L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 
7L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 
8L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 
7L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 
6L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 
6L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 
6L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 
6L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 8L, 
6L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 
7L, 6L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 
1L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 
8L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
7L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 
4L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 
6L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 
7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 
7L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 1L, 
6L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 
7L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 
5L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 
5L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 4L), p14 = c(7L, 9L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 
6L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 7L, 
5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 
3L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
7L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 10L, 
2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 
5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 
7L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 9L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 
6L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 
3L, 2L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
5L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 9L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 9L, 9L, 
5L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 10L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 
2L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 
9L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 
7L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
6L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 
5L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 9L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 
5L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 10L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 
7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 10L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
7L, 3L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 9L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
2L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 
9L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
7L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 
7L, 6L, 3L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 9L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 
8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 
2L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
7L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 9L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
6L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
7L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 
1L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
8L, 9L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 10L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
5L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 8L, 
3L, 3L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 
7L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 
4L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 
5L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 
2L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 
9L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 10L, 9L, 
7L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 9L, 
5L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 
8L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 7L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 5L, 9L, 7L, 10L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 
1L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 
3L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 9L, 10L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 8L, 3L, 
5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 8L, 10L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 
9L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 2L, 
9L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 3L, 8L, 6L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 
4L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 
8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 
9L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
9L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 4L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 8L, 
7L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 
5L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 3L, 
8L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 
4L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
10L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 
8L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 
7L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 9L, 
8L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 
8L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 9L, 4L, 7L, 
4L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 9L, 
8L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 
9L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 6L, 5L, 9L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 
8L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 2L, 9L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 
6L, 5L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 
8L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 10L, 
6L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 5L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 3L, 10L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 9L, 8L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 
3L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 5L, 9L, 2L, 7L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 
5L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 
4L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 
8L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 
7L, 10L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 8L)), .Names = c("p11", "p13", "p14"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1768L))

populacao <- structure(list(p11 = 1:28, Populacao = c(225L, 115L, 119L, 9L, 
36L, 310L, 8L, 568L, 230L, 193L, 569L, 145L, 4781L, 444L, 40L, 
193L, 11L, 672L, 4417L, 101L, 21L, 15L, 140L, 2061L, 466L, 1204L, 
302L, 87L)), .Names = c("p11", "Populacao"), row.names = c(NA, 
-28L), class = "data.frame")

dados_censo <- merge(dados_censo,populacao)
amostra <- svydesign(id=~1,strata=~p11,  data=dados_censo, fpc=~Populacao)
svytable(~ p13 + p14, amostra)
svychisq(~ p13 + p14, amostra)
```

Comment: Have you at least tabulated them one against the other? The error message will likely jump out if your categorical variables coincide, or one is a subset of the other, or there is some other strong dependence between them.

Comment: Yes, I tried look for something like this, but the data sounds ok to me (One category has 50% of zeros values, but i don't think this is the reason... may be?). Look the edit with the frequency table

Comment: Well, there's enough going on here to make the matrix poorly conditioned for a combination of small/zero cells, and the sheer size of the problem. Also, you may have a very unfortunate cut of strata and/or clusters through categories, so this could be an interaction of survey features with categories. If a very well coded and tested and polished `svychisq()` does not do it, little else will. I can try to replicate your thing in Stata, you would then need to share the relevant design and analysis variables.

Comment: could you please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?  code that exactly re-creates your problem on my computer and exactly nothing else.  :)

Comment: @AnthonyDamico and StasL: Added the data.

Answer (score 1):

If you tabulate within levels of p11, you will see several levels with all zero rows or very sparse entries:

```
 with( dados_censo, table(p13, p14, p11))
```

I suspect you are having problems in the estimation of the appropriate degrees of freedom and the construction of an adjustment to the Pearson-statistic. The data looks very sparse or with all-zero rows for p11 levels: 1-7, 9-12, 14-18, 20-28. Attempting to choose different adjustment methods fails. The failure is a solve call before the switching logic and all the methods use the same "Delta" matrix in one way or another